# How to connect multiple socket servers in python?

Tags: python, sockets

So, I have a server script in python and a client script. I want to use multiple server machines to host a single server script.

Here is my server script:

```
import socket 
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = "0.0.0.0"#socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"



clients = []

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")


    connected = True
    clients.append(conn)
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)

            for items in clients:
                items.send(msg.encode(FORMAT))

            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
            


            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")


           

            
            #conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()
        

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
    start()
```

so basically, I want to host this single script on multiple machines but they must have the same data like the client list should be same in all the machines and all the other variables.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: How would the client know which server to connect to? Check for ideas here: [HTTP redirection status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages). With the shared data, maybe the servers all connect together and use `socket.sendall(bytes[, flags])`

Comment: Also, if the `- 1` is refering to the current iteration's conn closing, `thread.start()` doesn't block and will print 1 less than desired

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).